# Tkinter: set method does not work in a function for toplevel window

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

For some reason, var.set(str) does not update var when a toplevel window is created from a function. The code below works when placed in the mainloop (without the function), though. When adding mainloop to the function it also works as intended. Is that intended behaviour?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

def function():
    mainFrame = ttk.Frame(root)
    mainFrame.grid(column =1, row =1)
    configureWindow = Toplevel(mainFrame)
    pathInfoContent = StringVar()
    graphPathFrame = ttk.Frame(root)
    graphPathFrame.grid(column = 1, row =1)
    graphPathLabel = ttk.Label(graphPathFrame, text = 'GraphViz Installation Path:')
    graphPathLabel.grid(column = 1, row =1)
    graphPathLabel3 = ttk.Label(graphPathFrame, textvariable = pathInfoContent)
    graphPathLabel3.grid(column = 2, row =1)
    pathInfoContent.set('Something')  

function()

mainloop()
```

Comment: It because `pathInfoContent` is garbage collected. You need to store `StringVar` variable outside the function and/or to make it global.

Comment: Thanks that's it!